# Searching an Array for a value that has 2 parts

Tags: arrays, string, search

Newbie back again.
I've written a piece of code that searches a string array using a search variable. The Array string is populated with a given set of data.
So the problem is that I can search using .contains for the strings "coke" "lemonade" but...I also have "7 up" and its the space thats causing the problems. And yes thats the point  - it has to be "7 up"
This is the for loop I'm using to iterate through the array

```
            for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
                if(name[i].toLowerCase().contains(targetSearch.toLowerCase()))
                    output += name[i] + "\n";
```

And I send output to print - thats fine.
Its also validated to only accept a targetSearch of at least 3 in length.
So when i enter 'lem' - lemonade prints. but '7 u' doesn't pass my validation of...
if(targetSearch.length()<3)...cause of the space.

So how do I allow for the space???
Please anyone?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle or code simulator in here so we can see full program

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you search in the array,
but it doesn't make a difference if there is a space
in a string:

```js
var a = "7 UP";
var arr = ["Coke", "Fanta", "7 UP", "Sprite"];

document.write(arr.indexOf(a));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I said I'm a Newbie and I was using the wrong .nextLine(); I cahnged it to .next(); and it worked. If I'd posted the entire program you would have spotted it.